What is the formula for a sum of sums $(1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + \dots + (1+2+ \dots +n))$?
So, the formula for a sum of numbers up to $k$ is $k(k+1)/2$. Let's call that $s(k)$. Now, is there a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n s(i)$ - a sum of the sums of numbers up to up to $n$?
Here is where I'm currently at: $$
s(1)+s(2)+\dots+s(n) = \frac{1\times2}2 + \frac{2\times3}2 + \dots + \frac{n(n+1)}2 =\\\ \\
= \frac12(\ (1\times2)+(2\times3)+\dots(n(n+1))\ )
$$
But where do I go next?

separate the linear and quadratic terms and use $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$

You have $s(i)=\frac12 i(i+1)=\frac12 i^2+\frac12 i$. So you need to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i$. You already calculated the second sum

Hi, welcome to Math SE. The $k$th triangle number, which you've called $s(k)$, is often denoted $T_k$.

With the help of @Andrei and @dezdichado, I have the solution.
$$
s(i)=\frac12i(i+1)=\frac12i^2+\frac12i = \frac12(i^2+i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n s(i) = \frac12 \times \left( \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n i \right) = \\
= \frac12 \times \left( \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + \frac{n(n+1)}2 \right)\\
$$
After some simplification, this comes out to be $(n(n+1)(n+2))\div6$.

Well done. You might also be interested in another approach using $s(k)=\binom{k+1}{2}$ that doesn't need knowledge of $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$.

@J.G. i'm too stupid for that LOL interesting idea though

By using commutativity and associativity, note that the sum $S$ you are computing consists of
$$S = n\cdot 1 + (n-1)\cdot 2 + (n-2)\cdot 3 +\dots + (n-(n-1))\cdot n$$
That is, $S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)(i+1)$. Now, expand the product in the sum, and use the formulas you received as hints in the comments.

To express as a telescoping series, write
$\tfrac12k(k+1)=\tfrac16[k(k+1)(k+2)-(k-1)k(k+1)].$
Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\tfrac12k(k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n\tfrac16[k(k+1)(k+2)-(k-1)k(k+1)].$$
Note that the negative component of each term of the right-hand series cancels with the positive component of the previous term. All that is left is
$$\tfrac16n(n+1)(n+2).$$
